# Need to move Java applications form Solaris 10 to AIX. Is there is Oracle or OpenJDK available for AIX platform?

Tags: solaris, aix, java

We need to move many Java applications that is build with Sun JDK runs on sun JRE in Solaris 10 to AIX.

We are concerned about the applicaion working the same on IBM J9 JRE.

Is there any Oracle or OpenJDk available for AIX platform or what might be a better solution to move Java applicaitons from Solaris to AIX.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990589/need-to-move-java-applications-form-solaris-10-to-aix-is-there-is-oracle-or-ope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We run on the native IBM JDK/JRE without issue.   We've had a couple issues with external tools using Sun specific classes (`com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser`, `SunX509`, a couple others).

We also use Tomcat and some of the other apache products without any major issues.   IBM's JRE has been very fast and robust for us.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the IBM solution is the best on IBM.  Its worth noting that IBM now supports the OpenJDK so the differences between them will narrow over time.

You may have migration issues, but I don't imagine they will be hard to fix. If you are really afraid to touch the application I would suggest you stick with the system you have.

Comment: Problem during the migration are usually not hard to fix, but they can be very hard to find in the first place, because they usually rely on unspecified behaviour.

Comment: Does openJDK which is similar to sun's JRE available on AIX?

Comment: @Joachim, I agree that how hard its to move depends heavily on the application and how it is written. esp if native libraries have been used. @tutysara, The source for OpenJDK is available and you could try to build it on AIX. I have never tried to do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

certifiable version of OpenJDK AIX has been announced in January 2013
please check the details from here 
http://openjdk.java.net/projects/ppc-aix-port/